# How to get programatically the list of sagemaker instance types ml.*?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

With the AWS CLI `ec2 describe-instance-types` I can get a list of all the EC2 instance types but Sagemaker Instance Types like `ml.t3.medium`, `ml.t3.large`, `ml.m5.xlarge`, etc are not there.

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=ml.*" --query "InstanceTypes[].{Type: InstanceType, MaxENI: NetworkInfo.MaximumNetworkInterfaces, IPv4addr: NetworkInfo.Ipv4AddressesPerInterface}" --output table
# returns no results
```

I know I can get the list of SageMaker Instance Types from https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/ but I really want to get it programmatically.

How can I get programatically the list of instance types supported in Sagemaker for a given region?

Comment: I've been poking around in the console, and it seems like they're hard-coded in the frontend and not fetched asynchronously from an API which is usually not a good sign :/

Comment: In the worst case, you can scrape it programmatically.

Comment: By programatically, I meant via the AWS API / AWS CLI, otherwise I will just just do it by hand. If the the list if hardcoded in the frontend like [Maurice said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456934/how-to-get-programatically-the-list-of-sagemaker-instance-types-ml?noredirect=1#comment133136958_75456934) then I'll also hardcode it myself in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the [answer from Gili](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470312/90580).

Using the aws CLI and jq :

```
aws --region us-east-1 pricing get-products \
  --service-code AmazonSageMaker \
  --filters Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=regionCode,Value=eu-north-1 \
  | jq -r '.PriceList[]|fromjson|select(.product.productFamily == "ML Instance")|.product.attributes.instanceName'\
|sort\
|uniq

ml.c5.12xlarge
ml.c5.18xlarge
ml.c5.24xlarge
ml.c5.2xlarge
ml.c5.4xlarge
ml.c5.9xlarge
ml.c5.large
...
ml.t3.2xlarge
ml.t3.large
ml.t3.medium
ml.t3.xlarge
```

it uses

- `aws pricing get-products`

  - `--region us-east-1` is important because the Pricing service is not widely available
  - `--filters Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=regionCode,Values=eu-north-1` to restrict the listing to products in `eu-north-1` region, the number of products for AmazonSageMaker alone across all regions is huge, so better to let AWS to filter out those early
- `jq` is used to further filter the output, it seems it's not possible to filter by `productFamily` at the `aws pricing get-products` so we need to do it with `jq`

  - `-r` removes the quotes from the output
  - `.PriceList[]` will iterate over all the prices returned by `aws pricing get-products`
  - `fromjson` will parse the each string as JSON (`.PriceList` is an array of strings)
  - `select(.product.productFamily == "ML Instance")` will filter out all other products
  - `.product.attributes.instanceName` extracts the instance type from each product.

Comment: Nice one! Please accept Ruben's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of ml instances with this CLI call ([doc](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/pricing/get-products.html)):

```
aws pricing get-products --service-code AmazonSageMaker --filters Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=location,Value="US East (N. Virginia)"
```

You'll need to filter the results further.
Note that a particular ml instance type might be available for a certain SageMaker feature like training, but not for inference. And be available in one region but not another.

If you're end goal is to get technical details, you could first fine the relevant ml.* instances (maybe even with regex), then use the EC2 describe instance type to get more details (just strip down the `ml.` prefix).

You can find relevant Python code in the "Total Cost" section of my notebook [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-training-jobs-benchmarks/blob/main/instance_types_RoBERTa_benchmark/instance_types_benchmark_roberta.ipynb).